# Sublime Text 2 auto suggest files for auto complete

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way for Sublime Text 2 to auto suggest directories and then files when adding a external script, href, etc. in a file? I love this when using Webstorm and would love to be able to do the same in ST2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [AutoFileName](https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName) does the job :)